# sql select query IN Clause returns nothing

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it possible to get any value from the parameters passed inside IN clause where 1 value returns nothing.

Example:

```
 select id, translation  
 from   <table>  
 where id in (1,2,36)    
    and (locale_id='EN' )
```

If id 2 has no values in table, is it possible to return NULL in place of no values at all.
Currently it returns only 2 values.

Comment: You can't *generate* rows from a `SELECT` statement. Either the rows are present, or they're not. You would need to have a table with the ID's in them and do a left join on it.

Comment: You can try putting the values in a temp table and then using a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

Comment: can you show sample data with expected output?

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
with cte as (
   select * 
   from (values (1),(2),(36) ) v(v)
)
select * 
from cte 
left join table1 t1 on t1.id=cte.v and (t1.locale_id='EN' )
```

you'll get at least on record per id

cte generates 3 records, each with one value `v` i prefer the syntax with cte over the following version (which should do the same)

```
select * 
from (values (1),(2),(36)) v(v)
left join table1 t1 on t1.id=v.v and (t1.locale_id='EN' )
```

the left join well read yourself : [http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp](http://w3schools%20about%20sql_join_left)

Comment: thats great, can you elobarate it a bit. as i made a quick change and add columns I require.

Comment: @VijayTripathi  wrote a bit more, how about you try each part